# Currying functions in Java

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, currying

```
    def check( x: Int, y: Int) (z: Int) = {
        x+y+z
    }                                 //> check: (x: Int, y: Int)(z: Int)Int

    def curried = check _             //> curried: => (Int, Int) => Int => Int
    def z = curried(0,0)              //> z: => Int => Int

    z(3)                              //> res0: Int = 3
    check(1,2)(3)                     //> res1: Int = 6
    check(1,2)(_)                     //> res2: Int => Int = <function1>
```

I have this code in Scala and what I'm trying to achieve is to call check in this way

```
check(1,2)
```

without the third parameter in order to call check in three ways

```
check(1,2)(3) // with three parameters 
z(3)          // with just one and 
check(1,2) with two parameters.
```

How can I do this in Scala and Java? Can I declare z as an implicit in Java?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does java support Currying?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134278/does-java-support-currying)

Comment: I'm aware of this post but unfortunately didn't help me to understand how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
def check( x: Int, y: Int) (z: Int)
```

When you use the syntax sugar above to create curried functions, you have to use the `_` assign the partially applied function to a value. This way you are not invoking the function, but creating a function value instead.

```
val z = curried(0,0) _
```

However, if you do not use the syntax sugar:

```
def check( x: Int, y: Int) = (z:Int) => x+y+z
```

Then you can call it the way you want it:

```
check(1,2)    //res2: Int => Int = <function1>
z(3)          // res3: Int = 6
check(1,2)(3) // res4: Int = 6
```

Note that you do not have to use `_` to, for example, pass the result of the partially applied function as a parameter to another function.

```
def filter(xs: List[Int], p: Int => Boolean): List[Int] =
    if (xs.isEmpty) xs
    else if (p(xs.head)) xs.head :: filter(xs.tail, p)
    else filter(xs.tail, p)

def modN(n: Int)(x: Int) = ((x % n) == 0)

filter(List(1,2,3,4,5), modN(2)) //res6: List[Int] = List(2, 4)
```