# What does lambda with 2 arrows mean in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, currying

I have read several Java 8 tutorials before.

Right now I encountered following topic:
[Does java support Currying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134278/does-java-support-currying)

Here, I see following code:

```
IntFunction<IntUnaryOperator> curriedAdd = a -> b -> a + b;
System.out.println(curriedAdd.apply(1).applyAsInt(12));
```

I understand that this example sum 2 elements but I cannot understand the construction:

```
a -> b -> a + b;
```

According to the left part of expression, this row should implement following function:

```
R apply(int value);
```

Before this, I only met lambdas only with one arrow.

Comment: Do you understand what currying means?  That's pretty integral to this question.

Comment: It's just a lambda that returns a lambda.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

If you express this as non-shorthand lambda syntax or pre-lambda Java anonymous class syntax it is clearer what is happening...

The original question. Why are two arrows? Simple, there are two functions being defined... The first function is a function-defining-function, the second is the result of that function, which also happens to be function. Each requires an `->` operator to define it.

### Non-shorthand

```
IntFunction<IntUnaryOperator> curriedAdd = (a) -> {
    return (b) -> {
        return a + b;
    };
};
```

### Pre-Lambda before Java 8

```
IntFunction<IntUnaryOperator> curriedAdd = new IntFunction<IntUnaryOperator>() {
    @Override
    public IntUnaryOperator apply(final int value) {
        IntUnaryOperator op = new IntUnaryOperator() {
            @Override
            public int applyAsInt(int operand) {
                return operand + value;
            }
        };
        return op;
    }
};
```

Comment: pre-lambda requires a `final int value`

Comment: Yes, you're correct, but I wrote that still using a Java 8 compiler which allows you to use things that are "effectively final"

Comment: @njzk2 in java 8 - not. it is effectively final

Comment: @gstackoverflow yes, but then java 8 is not `pre-lambda`

Comment: you can use pre-lambda style in java 8 too. I wrote it JFY

Comment: Wasn't lambdas done just so SO folks could score points ? :-)

Answer (score 49):

An `IntFunction<R>` is a function `int -> R`. An `IntUnaryOperator` is a function `int -> int`.

Thus an `IntFunction<IntUnaryOperator>` is a function that takes an `int` as parameter and return a function that takes an `int` as parameter and return an `int`.

```
a -> b -> a + b;
^    |         |
|     ---------
|         ^
|         |
|         The IntUnaryOperator (that takes an int, b) and return an int (the sum of a and b)
|
The parameter you give to the IntFunction
```

Maybe it is more clear if you use anonymous classes to "decompose" the lambda:

```
IntFunction<IntUnaryOperator> add = new IntFunction<IntUnaryOperator>() {
    @Override
    public IntUnaryOperator apply(int a) {
        return new IntUnaryOperator() {
            @Override
            public int applyAsInt(int b) {
                return a + b;
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 30):

Adding parentheses may make this more clear:

```
IntFunction<IntUnaryOperator> curriedAdd = a -> (b -> (a + b));
```

Or probably intermediate variable may help:

```
IntFunction<IntUnaryOperator> curriedAdd = a -> {
    IntUnaryOperator op = b -> a + b;
    return op;
};
```

Answer (score 24):

Let's rewrite that lambda expression with parentheses to make it more clear:

```
IntFunction<IntUnaryOperator> curriedAdd = a -> (b -> (a + b));
```

So we are declaring a function taking an `int` which returns a `Function`. More specifically, the function returned takes an `int` and returns an `int` (the sum of the two elements): this can be represented as an [`IntUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html).

Therefore, `curriedAdd` is a function taking an `int` and returning an `IntUnaryOperator`, so it can be represented as [`IntFunction<IntUnaryOperator>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntFunction.html).

Answer (score 10):

It's two lambda expressions.

```
IntFunction<IntUnaryOperator> curriedAdd = 
  a -> { //this is for the fixed value
    return b -> { //this is for the add operation
      return a + b;
    };
  }

IntUnaryOperator addTwo = curriedAdd.apply(2);
System.out.println(addTwo.applyAsInt(12)); //prints 14
```

Answer (score 8):

If you look at [`IntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntFunction.html) it might become clearer: `IntFunction<R>` is a `FunctionalInterface`. It represents a function that takes an `int` and returns a value of type `R`.

In this case, the return type `R` is also a `FunctionalInterface`, namely an `IntUnaryOperator`. So the *first* (outer) function itself returns a function.

In this case: When applied to an `int`, `curriedAdd` is supposed to return a function that again takes an `int` (and returns again `int`, because that's what `IntUnaryOperator` does).

In functional programming it is common to write the type of a function as `param -> return_value` and you see exactly that here. So the type of `curriedAdd` is `int -> int -> int` (or `int -> (int -> int)` if you like that better).

Java 8's lambda syntax goes along with this. To define such a function, you write

```
a -> b -> a + b
```

which is very much similar to actual lambda calculus:

```
λa λb a + b
```

`λb a + b` is a function that takes a single parameter `b` and returns a value (the sum). `λa λb a + b` is a function that accepts a single parameter `a` and returns another function of a single parameter. `λa λb a + b` returns `λb a + b` with `a` set to the parameter value.