# Implementing compose using only Function<> in java 8

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

In the book [Functional Programming in Java](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-java) the author builds a compose function using only the `Function<T, U>` interface (the interface however is not one shipped with Java 8 but very similar though) the snippet of which is show below

```
public interface Function<T, U> {
  U apply(T arg);
}
```

though I could understand the method version of compose below, which takes in 2 functions and return a composed function

```
public static final Function<Integer, Integer> compose (final Function<Integer, Integer> f1, 
                                   final Function<Integer, Integer> f2) {
         arg -> f1.apply(f2.apply(arg));
}
```

I just couldn't get my head around the below compose implementation with Function<> and lambdas

```
static Function<Function<Integer, Integer>,
            Function<Function<Integer, Integer>,
                    Function<Integer, Integer>>> compose =
            x -> y -> z -> x.apply(y.apply(z));
```

PS: couldn't get my mind out of this and move forward with remaining sections :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834611/how-to-do-function-composition maybe

Comment: I see how to compose two fxn with the given functions, but concern was about how to implement that compose function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820722/what-does-lambda-with-2-arrows-mean-in-java-8/32820940

Comment: This really lacks C pointers!

Answer (score 5):

Referring to a `Function<Integer, Integer>` as an integer function, what you have there is a function that maps {an integer function} to {a function mapping an integer function to another integer function}.

Specifically, when given an integer function `x`, it returns a function that, given an integer function `y`, returns an integer function that maps an integer `z` to `x(y(z))`.

```
Given a function x
Returns a function that:
    Given a function y
    Returns a function that:
        Given an integer z
        Returns x(y(z))
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me use a simpler λ-notation omitting types, where `λx.E` means a function that takes an argument `x` and returns the value of `E`.  For instance, `λx. λy. x+y` is a function that takes `x` and returns `λy. x+y`, which itself is a function that takes `y` and returns `x+y`.  Let us also write `λ(x,y).E` for a function that takes *two* arguments `x` and `y`, and returns the value of `E`.  For example, `λ(x,y). x+y` is a function that takes `x` and `y` *at once* and returns `x+y`.

Then the "two arguments at once" version of `compose` is: `λ(f,g). λx.f(g(x))`

The second, "one-by-one" version is: `λf. λg. λx.f(g(x))`

Everything else that looks scary in the Java code is just type annotations.  Both `f` and `g` (as well as the result of `compose`) have type `Function < Integer, Integer >` .  Let's write this type as `T`.  Then the second version of compose has type `Function < T, Function < T, T > >`.

P.S.  Functions like `λx. λy. E` are called *curried*, while `λ(x,y). E` is *uncurried*.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Answer (score 0):

This type of illustration might make more sense using different types and/or generics.

```
Function<Function<R, S>,
         Function<Function<T, R>,
                  Function<T, S>>> compose = x -> y -> z -> x.apply(y.apply(z));
```

edit: Types were incorrectly placed (this is why it's a better exercise when they're different)